# applying validation on a textbox that matches the list of an autocomplete extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have 2 textbox entityName and addEntity. There's an autocomplete extender on entityName textbox. I want to validate the textbox addEntity such that if name typed in addEntity textbox exists in the autocomplete extender list of entityName textbox, it should show error.How do i do? Please mention the LOC for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CustomerValidator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) and validate data side server with event **ServerValidate** or/and side client use the property ClientValidationFunction for specify a customer javascript function for validate  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction(v=vs.110).aspx).

The solution is valid of course for ASP.NET WebForms

Comment: public void entityExists (object s, ValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            DataTable dtOutsideEntity =COIOrganizationCollection.GetOrganizations(prefixText);
 for (int i = 0; i < dtOutsideEntity.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (args.newEntityName.Text == args.dtOutsideEntity.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString())
                    args.IsValid = false;
                else
                    args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }

Comment: the red line.. anyways its resolved now. i had to make the changes in SP, which i did. thank you for the response